# Handling view events with RxAndroid

Tags: android, observable, rx-android

I see plenty of code examples showing the use of ViewObservable to handle view events. Unfortunately however it seems that ViewObservable was removed from the latest RxAndroid release. Has this api been deprecated? And if so what would be the preferred way of handling view events now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [RxAndroid 1.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v1.0.0), RxAndroid's scope has been significantly reduced, and the view bindings have moved to the [RxBinding library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding).